# House being built but I think the brick is poorly done

Tags: brick, masonry

So our house is being built and the brick just went up on the house (it isn't structural).

I personally feel that the job was done extremely poorly. I don't know much about masonry but from my knowledge, the mortar spaces should be pretty consistent (unless going around an arch or something) but almost every brick has a different spacing distance. Also the size of the mortar spaces are from < 1/4in. all the way to 1 in.+. From my understanding they should be ~3/8 of an inch +-1/8 of an inch. Some of the spaces are 1+ inches. Builder says that what I'm seeing mostly is just excess mortar and that they will be pressure washing the brick to make it look better. But I don't feel that will help.

Am I out of line to think this brick was installed poorly?

Example pictures.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/THBnk.jpg

There are a lot of other issues (e.g. they didn't space out the bricks correctly and one-half of a wall is almost all brown and the other half is all white brick). Gaps, and spaces in the brick etc.

Comment: Serious pressure washing is going to blow that brick right off the house.

Comment: Not sure how to take that. Not sure if you mean it's so poorly done it will blow the brick off the house, or that pressure washing in general is bad.

Comment: That is really a bad job. It may hold up very well, but technique is lacking

Comment: @Jack So is there any fixing this without ripping it all out? I'm going to the builder and discussing this issue and all the other issues with them that I've found (the bricks being uneven, leveling issues, etc).

Comment: The builder will not want to do it if is just bad craftsmanship. If he is willing, kudos to him. The only way way it would be or could be torn down if the proper flashings were not integrated into the brick coursing. Then that would be a matter of who is responsible for such things and if it is in the plans, what is in the contract etc.

Comment: Horizontally it looks ok but the verticals are a mess. I agree with Jack. Pressure will only clean the mess off the brick. Since it is not structural there may not be anything that can be done legally.

Comment: That looks really bad bricklaying to me. You can be sure that cleaning excess mortar will not make a *significant* difference.

Comment: Sheesh ... I'm an electronics guy and I can lay bricks better than that ...

Comment: You probably don't have a legal case so far as brick color goes unless you specified somewhere that the bricks must be distributed (or of matching color) in the first place.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I agree and if it would have been the only major issue I would have told them but not worried about it. But I've got other pictures I didnt show of cracks in bricks, mortar joints not filled in, brick falling off the house, brick leaning left or right not being straight, walls not being plumb, (the wall is leaning in towards the house, 5.5 inches at bottom and 4.5 to 5 inches at the top. Stick a level on the brick and its leaning towards the house. Plumb line shows the same thing. Overall I think it's a crap job and based on feedback I feel like I'm not being overly critical.

Comment: I mean: the pointing is so poorly done and the spacing is so wide that a pressure washer could easily remove chunks of mortar and loosen bricks from the wall. - Pressure washing in general is not harmful.

Answer (score 4):

I have laid thousands of bricks and that is crap work! Don't pay for that, and there is no way to fix it it must come off and be redone. They should be ashamed of themselves, a new house that looks terrible. Stick up for yourself and the investment your making and make them redo there work.

Comment: That's the sentiment that I've been given from everyone that I've talked to about this. Spoke with builder this afternoon and he's going to be talking with the brick mason tomorrow morning and will get back with me on how they think they will be able to resolve this.